# change EEE format to another language

Tags: angularjs, date, date-format, cjk

How can i change EEE format at will?

```
if ($scope.languageCode == "jp") {
    $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy年M月d日(EEE)';
   //Should i try some switch case here?
     } else if($scope.languageCode == "en") {
    $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy/M/d (EEE)';
     };
```

html

```
<td>{{today| date:dateFormat}}</td>
```

[image]

Comment: it is better to use switch case with default value